# How can we delete bigquery snapshot created by table decorators?

Tags: google-bigquery

Table Name : my_data

I wrote a query "**select * from [my-datawarehouse:my_store_data.my_data@-86400000-]**" to fetch last 1 day data  on 24th April. As per Big-query document, It created a snapshot from the query.

Now, I am running the above query and It's returning the old data, not the recent last 1day data.

So How can I update the snapshot data/delete the snapshot?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I have completely missed one case. Yesterday I have loaded(append to table) few old data of April-May to my table. And it created a confusion to me.

Answer (score 2):

The query doesn't create snapshot - BigQuery automatically creates snapshots as you add data, this query just retrieves the data that was added in the last 24 hours.
It should return the most recently added data within 24 hours.

Note, that table decorators allow time travel back only up to 7 days (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) - if you want to keep older snapshots, you would have to save them into separate table yourself (and pay for storage)

Comment: Thanks for your early response. I have missed one case and I was totally lost. Yesterday I have loaded(append to table) few old data of April-May. And it's create a confusion to me. Using decorators Can I get last 6 months data by using @-15552000000- ? Or there is any limitation of date range?

Comment: Updated answer: Only up to 7 days back.